# Active rooms tooltip doesn't really know how to count, or just too optimistic

Tags: bug, chat, tooltips

Tooltip over "rooms" tab in [all rooms](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=all&sort=active) page is quite wrong:

> [image]

There are only 4 rooms active in the last 120 minutes, and only 8 active in the last 24 hours. Can the tooltip please be fixed?

<sub>P.S.
While writing this, the number changed to 11... (and no new room got any activity)</sub>

Comment: @Pat no, note how part of the rooms are empty, and while asking the question it turned from 10 to 11 and the list of the rooms did not change at all. I suspect a server side cache not being cleared for days, but can't really know.

Comment: Oh my, it's getting bigger... **what have I done?!** :D

Comment: @Pat well, just confirmed active users don't affect it - joined with my sock, posted a message - no change in the number. :/

Comment: Aren't some chat rooms hidden to us? For moderator and dev internal stuff, etc?

Comment: @Patrick only one here on MSE: http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1 (dunno its name)

Comment: And [secret chat room #2](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/900) as you found in chat.

Answer (score 2):

The number in the button and the tool tip seem to include hidden chat rooms too. (There seem to be more hidden rooms on MSE chat that initially though)

On StackOverflow's chat, there are 54 active chat rooms, while counting the list actually yields 35 chat rooms meeting the criteria.

On Chat.SE the numbers are 51 counted / 67 listed.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the case, each SE team got its own private room and they're chatting right here behind our backs. :)